# JEST run test inside an iframe

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jestjs, jsdom

There's a way to run a test (or an entire test suite) inside an iframe?

Specifically, I have to test some js functions that are checking if they are executed inside a cross origin frame or not

Comment: how does your function looks like? does it check `window.parent.origin`?

Comment: it checks window.top.location.href

Comment: try with [mocking properties](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-methods-which-are-not-implemented-in-jsdom) on global `window`